# Change in acceleration due to gravity because of rotation of earth

Tags: rotational-dynamics, potential, rotation, angular-velocity

[image]

The formula above is the equation for acceleration due to gravity when earth rotates. G is the original acceleration. 
Can someone explain how this formula came?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the above formula $g'$ is the component (directed towards centre of earth) of the net acceleration due to centrifugal force which is due to rotation of earth and acceleration due gravitational force of earth.

i.e. $g'=g-R\omega^2\cos^2\lambda$ where $R\omega^2\cos^2\lambda$ is the component of centrifugal force away from the centre of earth.
[image]

Comment: This is an approximation, relying on the fact that $R\omega^2  \ll g$ - see duplicate.

Comment: Yes, thanks for adding that (as the length of vectors in the above image doesn't show so ) and the above approach to find change in acceleration due to gravity is assuming earth as a **perfect sphere**.

Comment: @Nayan, thank you very much! That was very clear. I have one question though. I can understand on the earth frame that centrifugal force is the pseudo force added and it acts outward but could you explain this phenomenon to me in an inertial frame? As in say I'm in outer space and I know earth's gravity is the only force acting and it is pulling bodies inward, how would I explain outward acceleration?

Comment: When a frame is in rotational motion around a axis (called axis of rotation) its the centripetal force that make it move around the axis changing its direction of motion. Let there be a box and an observer into the box and the box is set in a rotational motion held by a rope to certain pole which is held tight at a certain place and its only the centripetal force that 's acting on the box then the observer in the box will say that there's a force that make him accelerate in the box to explain the acceleration in the box frame [as there's no centripetal force acting on him, it's his relative

Comment: observation as it's the box that experience an acceleration (assuming there's nothing holding him in the box)] Similarly you are accelerating towards earth at $g$ relative to centre of earth but relative to earth surface you are accelerating towards earth surface at $g'$ because the earth experience a centripetal acceleration and thus you seem to be approaching towards earth surface at less acceleration than g and the weight you measure is $mg'$. A frame in gravitational field is not really an inertial frame though local or very small frame can be thought as one (depends on variance of  field

Comment: in frame). You need centrifugal force to describe motions in accelerating frames (rotating frames) and other pseudo forces too. Centrifugal force is just the absence of centripetal force on you which don't make you rotate with the frame. In outer space or accelerating towards earth in the earth's rotating frame one may need to define few more forces out of which centrifugal force will be one (if you are not moving with same velocity by magnitude one will need to be while being at rest in rotating frame at $R$). Or if one is in an orbit round the earth there will be no need to introduce

Comment: centrifugal force in that orbiting frame (assuming small) as the whole frame is in a freefall.